# i am getting below problem on installing packages

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-pub

any one can help me?

mine project is about news feed i want that output

```
[Flutter-News-App] flutter pub upgrade
Running "flutter pub get" in Flutter-News-App...                Resolving dependencies...
Connection closed before full header was received
pub finished with exit code 69
exit code 69

Because no versions of mockito match >4.1.1 <4.1.1+1 and mockito >=4.1.1+1 <4.1.2 depends on test_api >=0.2.1 <0.4.0, mockito >4.1.1 <4.1.2 requires test_api >=0.2.1 <0.4.0.
And because mockito >=4.1.2 <=5.0.0-nullsafety.7 depends on test_api ^0.2.19-nullsafety, mockito >4.1.1 <=5.0.0-nullsafety.7 requires test_api >=0.2.1 <0.4.0.
And because mockito 4.1.1 depends on test_api ^0.2.1 and every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on test_api 0.4.12, mockito >=4.1.1 <=5.0.0-nullsafety.7 is incompatible with flutter_test from sdk.
So, because flutter_news_app depends on both flutter_test from sdk and mockito ^4.1.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because flutter_news_app depends on both flutter_test from sdk and mockito ^4.1.1, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

Comment: it means that package you are trying to install is conflicting with other packages so you can do 2 thing, 1) over those dependency 2) downgrade/upgrade dependency until it resolves.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are upgrading or just installing, otherwise I think running
`flutter pub get` will solve your issue